# Remove All the occurrence of Word from Sentence Using Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

Hello I want to remove words from sentence below. how can i do this with regular expressions

```
ABC (+£768.00):Yes, 1 Top Access with 2 Socket (+£28.00):Yes , 2 USB and 2 RJ45 (Black)
```

I want to remove all the occurrence of words which start with "(+" and ends with "):".

For ex: i want to remove "**(+£768.00):**" and "**(+£28.00):**" from above line.

Please help me with this.

Thank You

Comment: Kindly add your code-efforts in your question.

Comment: @SIHala Any update from your end?

Answer (score 1):

Just do as the pattern demands using below regex:

```
\(\+.*?\)\:
```

Match `(+` as is by escaping followed by non-greedy matches of 0 or more characters ending with `):` again needing to be escaped. Use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace the match with an empty string.

```
<?php

echo preg_replace('/\(\+.*?\)\:/', '', 'ABC (+£768.00):Yes, 1 Top Access with 2 Socket (+£28.00):Yes , 2 USB and 2 RJ45 (Black)');
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yfvasfmf)